# Laravel - Ajax image upload - file is empty

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

when i try to upload my file with ajax, the $file is empty.

I tried with:

$file = Input::file('image');
$file= $request->file('image');

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#update_form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{{route('admin/users/update')}}',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.error').fadeOut();
                success(data);
                load_data('{{route('admin/users/edit')}}', '{{ $user->id }}', '{{ $user->part }}');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $('.success').fadeOut();
                errors(data);
            }
        })
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function updateUser(Request $request){

    //$file = Input::file('image');
    $file= $request->file('image');

    return \Response::json( $file );

}
```

Route:

```
    Route::post('admin/users/update', ['as' => 'admin/users/update', 'uses' => 'admin\UserController@updateUser']);
```

Form:

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['id' => 'update_form', 'files' => true]) !!}

<div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label(trans('User image')) }}
        {!! Form::file('image', null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('Image')]) !!}
    </div>

    {{ Form::hidden('id') }}
    {{ Form::hidden('part', app('request')->input('part')) }}

    {!! Form::submit(trans('Save changes'), ['class' => 'pull-right btn btn-success submit', 'id' => 'submit' ]) !!}

</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Repsonse is empty or:  {}

response image:

https://gyazo.com/04e431f16237dfada40c864df96ad412

Thank you!

Comment: You need a jQuery plugin to upload files via AJAX (easier than your own implementation), check out https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

param is your server method parameters

```
FormData fd =new FormData();
fd.append('param',$('input[type=file]').files[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 6.x** Ah finally  nailed it down, for me the way its worked is first i have get the form by it's form id using jQuery then create a new FormData instance passing form through the constructor then if you need anything pass to server side as key value pair use append function.

```
<form id="form_id" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="title">App name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id ="title_id" class="form-control" placeholder="App name"><br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" id="image" name="cover_image" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
           </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="WebApp.CategoryController.onClickAppSubmitButton()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit </button>
    </form>

var form = $("#form_id")[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append('parent_id','0');
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url: url_app_post,
        method: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (result) {
            var data_array = $.parseJSON(result);
            if (data_array.status == "200") {
                messageHtml += WebApp.CategoryController.getAlertMessage("alert-success", data_array.message);
            } else {
                messageHtml += WebApp.CategoryController.getAlertMessage("alert-danger", data_array.message);
            }

            $(messageView).html(messageHtml);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            messageHtml += WebApp.CategoryController.getAlertMessage("alert-danger",
                WebApp.CategoryController.getjqXHRmessage(jqXHR, exception));

            $(messageView).html(messageHtml);
        }

    })

 function storeCategory(Request $request, $type){
        try{
            $fileNameToStore='no_image.jpg';
            if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
                $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
                $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fileNameToStore=$fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);

            }
            $cat = new Category();
            $cat->title = $request->title;
            $cat->parent_id = $request->parent_id;
            $cat->cover_image=$fileNameToStore;
            $cat->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
            $cat->save();
            return json_encode(array("message"=>"This ".$type." successfully added", "status" => "200"));

        }catch(Exception $e){
            return  json_encode(array("message"=>$type." failed to insert: ".$e->getMessage(), "status" => "403"));
        }

    }
```